# How to compare dates in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Need to compare dates which are in the format - yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS

I have tried to use Date.Parse but Groovy Sandbox is not allowed and I need to compare within a scripted pipeline.

```
No such static method found: staticMethod java.util.Date parse java.lang.String java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such static method found: staticMethod java.util.Date parse java.lang.String java.lang.String
    at
```

Comment: I may be even wrong that it is not allowed, it may not be available looking at the message but we have a restricted environment so wont be able to run lot of groovy which is usually available.

Comment: You should consider the newer LocalDateTime instead of Date. Less hassle than Date in Jenkins pipelines. LocalDateTime.parse(...) will convert your string. Then google how to compare two LocalDateTime objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a ready-to-use code, please find the below code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

Date parseStringToDate(String createdDateStr) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
    dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(createdDateStr)
    return parsedDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either [need to approve the `Date.parse`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/), or use the sandbox allowed one

```
 new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(input)
```

Comment: trying this out, I am assuming the output can be then compare with the current date which needs to be in the same format.

Comment: thanks this helped to convert the string to Date format and compare.

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to accept the answer if that worked for you.

Comment: For me, this throws the error `unable to resolve class SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @alex I got the same error. After adding "import java.text.SimpleDateFormat" it is fixed.